# Error al crear un spinner en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

Al intentar crear un `Spinner` con su adaptador y datos ya dentro creado me da un error de `NullPointerException`, y no se donde se da dado que todo esta creado.

```
public class PartidaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button bAyuda;
private Button bTirar;
private ImageView dado;
private ImageView dado2;
private SoundPool sp;
private int sonidoDado=0;
private TextView nombreJugador;
private int turno;
private String valor,valorRecibido;
private Spinner spinnerValores;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pantalla_partida);

    bAyuda = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonAyudaPartida);
    bTirar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonTirar);
    dado = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Dado);
    dado2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Dado2);
    nombreJugador = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombreJugador);
    spinnerValores = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.eleccionTirada);

    ArrayList<Valor> listaValores = new ArrayList<Valor>();

    listaValores.add(new Valor(1,"Kiriki"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(2,"Ladrillo"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(3,"Pareja"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(4,"10"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(5,"9"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(6,"7"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(7,"6"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(8,"5"));
    listaValores.add(new Valor(9,"4"));

    ArrayAdapter<Valor> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<Valor>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,listaValores);
    adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerValores.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Pongo ahora lo que me dice el error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.alex.proyecto, PID: 16525
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alex.proyecto/com.example.alex.proyecto.PartidaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.alex.proyecto.PartidaActivity.onCreate(PartidaActivity.java:66)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te esta diciendo que la referencia del **Spinner** es nula. Tienes que confirmar si el Spinner en xml tiene el mismo **id** que le pasas como parámetro al método `findViewById()`. Que en este caso es `eleccionTirada`. Confirma en xml si el Spinner tiene ese mismo id.

Ó tienes que confirmar que el Spinner se encuentra en el **layout** que estas inflando con el método `setContentView();`. El layout que estas inflando es `pantalla_partida`, asegúrate de que ese sea el layout que contiene el Spinner.

Si todo esta bien y el problema persiste as un **Clean Project**. Esta opción se encuentra en la opción **Build** de la barra de herramientas de Android Studio.